# Abs and minBound

Tags: haskell, math

When playing around with minBound for various instances, I tried

```
> minBound :: Int
=> -9223372036854775808
```

which seems reasonable.

However,

```
> abs minBound :: Int 
=> -9223372036854775808
```

How is this possible? Shouldn't `abs x >= 0`, assuming `x :: Int`?

Is there some sort of understanding of semantics I am missing here?

Comment: I'm hesitant to post this as an answer, because I'm not certain - but I think it's to do with overflow. `maxBound :: Int` is `9223372036854775807`, which is 1 less than what you would think of as the absolute value of the minBound. So the absolute value you're after overflows, and presumably therefore wraps around to the minBound. I think. (Someone please correct me if I'm wrong, or expand on this if I'm right.)

Comment: I think you're right (I just posted that as an answer at about the same moment). But I don't think the Haskell standard guarantees that behavior in any case, so you probably can't rely on the value being wrapped around to `minBound`.

Comment: In 2-complement notation, there are _two_ solutions of the equation `x = -x`. One is zero (obviously), the other one is `minBound`. `abs minBound` likely tests if its argument is negative (and it is), and then returns `- minBound`, which is `minBound`. This is probably not a guaranteed behavior, but it should be expected on 2-complement systems.

Comment: Ah, ok. While I checked this by doing `abs (-9223372036854775808)` and got what I expected (9223372036854775808), I did so in GHCi, and so I assume that the type defaulting there is for Integer, not Int?

Comment: ^ yes, due to (extended) defaulting rules

Comment: Incidentally the behavior you notice is behind a bug that is almost everywhere in number parsing (at least I literally fixed it in three different places in the span of a week in my own and others code, during one project), in which you do: `if the first character is "-" negate the parse of what follows`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Prelude> minBound :: Int
-9223372036854775808
Prelude> maxBound :: Int
9223372036854775807
```

Note that the number `9223372036854775808` is not representable as an integer. This is a consequence of the [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation likely being used in the background here. The absolute value of `minBound` cannot be represented as a member of the type `Int`, so you end up getting an overflowing value.